Incremental cound of child nodes in neo4j
My schema has employee nodes and reports_to relations.
Id like a cypher that adds a property for each node with with the number of nodes that report_to, considering all subnodes
This is my current attempt, but is not returning correcrly
MATCH (e:Employee {name: "jhon doe"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)<-[r:REPORTS_TO*]-(ep:Employee)
WITH e, COUNT(r) AS nr, r, ep
SET e.nr = nr
RETURN e, nr, r, ep

in my sample data the root node should count 250 but is only returning 1

It is generally a bad idea to store such a count property, since every every time you add/delete any REPORTS_TO relationship you would also have to find and correct every affected count property. That adds a lot of complexity to your code and is expensive. It is generally better to just calculate the count as needed instead of storing it.

In your WITH clause, e r and ep all act as grouping keys, and COUNT(r) will always return 1. To get the correct count, you need to group only on e.
To do this, and assuming you need to keep your RETURN as is, you can (1) aggregate all r and ep per e with COLLECT, (2) count the number of ep in  the collection of r with size and set the property nr to that value (3) UNWIND each collection to get each report on a separate row:
MATCH (e:Employee {name: "john doe"}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)<-[r:REPORTS_TO*]-(ep:Employee) 
WITH e, COLLECT(r) AS rs, COLLECT(ep) AS eps
WITH *, size(rs) AS nr 
SET e.nr = nr
WITH *
UNWIND rs AS r 
UNWIND eps AS ep 
RETURN e, nr, r, ep

